# 8-digit odd numbers, digit "4" occurs three times and digit "6" occurs two times.

Tags: combinatorics

[Combinatorics]:
How many 8-digit odd numbers, where digit "4" occurs exactly three times and digit "6" occurs exactly two times, exist ?

These numbers are 44400661, 46464123, etc....

Comment: Please we write your thoughts and attempt about the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!   This is not a 'please do my HW' site, so please tell us something about what you tried or what your thoughts are. Please add this to your Post, or it will get closed fairly quickly

Comment: As a suggestion, if you are getting lost in the details, I'd try a similar problem with fewer possibilities.  Suppose I want $3$ digit odd numbers in which the digit $8$ occurs exactly once.  You can count those by hand and use that to check your methodology.

Comment: Please give me mathematic formula and I will count it myself.

Comment: I don't know how to begin to make a solution.

Comment: I know that I should use binomial theorem, by how in details ?

Comment: I gave you a place to begin.  Try the simpler problem.  That one you can definitely do by hand, if nothing else.  this problem has nothing to do with the binomial theorem.

Comment: @gtx570 Mathematics is not about plugging values into formulas ... it's about understanding why those formulas hold or are applicable to a specific problem in the first place.  lulu gave you a perfectly good suggestion for coming to such an understanding: start with some smaller examples, see what happens, and try to detect a pattern. You're not going to learn anything from having the right formula, or complete answer, being given to you.

Comment: @lulu, the OP may have meant to say binomial *coefficients* (which do come into play).

Comment: @BarryCipra  Ah, that makes sense.

Comment: I fully agree with the commenters who urged the OP to include a description of what they had tried and where they were stuck.  At the same time, it's worth noting that this problem is a bit trickier than it might at first appear, as evidenced by the fact that the were two completely wrong solutions that were self-deleted and that the remaining solution had a couple of errors that needed to be corrected.  The moral for the OP:  *Everyone* makes mistakes, so don't worry if you're having a hard time solving a problem!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if the number is odd, then there are $5$ choices for the final digit, and none of those choices is $4$ or $6$.

After that, we can count how many ways there are to place the $4$'s and $6$'s. They can't go in the final spot so we can count them as $\binom73\times\binom42$.

Finally, there are two places left completely free, but they can't be occupied by $4$ or $6$, so we multiply by $8^2$

This gives us an answer: $5\times\binom73\times\binom42\times 64$, but this isn't quite right. We will have counted some $7$-digit numbers this way, by placing $0$ in the initial spot. If we subtract all numbers with $0$ up front, we should have our answer. This count is similar to the one we've already done:

$$\left(5\times\binom73\times\binom42\times 64\right) - \left(5\times\binom63\times\binom32\times 8\right)$$

Can you simplify it from there?

Comment: "4 occurs **exactly** two times" so in the "places left completely free" do we really have ten options?

Comment: Ooh, good catch! I'll fix that.

Comment: Yes ! 5 x 64 x (7!/(7-3)!x3!) x (4!/(4-2)!x2!) - 5 x 8 x (6!/(6-3)!x3!) x (3!/(3-2)!x2!)

Comment: Result is 64 800.

Comment: That's what I got, too 

Comment: I made a C# program to compute it, and result is identical !

Comment: using System;
using System.Linq;
class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) 
  {
    int n=0;
    for (int i=10000000;i<99999999;i++)
    {
      if (i % 2 == 0) continue;
      string temp = i.ToString();
      var count4 = temp.Count(x => x == '4');
      var count6 = temp.Count(x => x == '6'); 
      if (count4==3 && count6==2) n++;
    }
    Console.WriteLine (n);
  }
}